# How to select and bold the whole worksheet with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am a beginner with Apache POI library.

in VBA, I know I can select and bold the whole worksheet with following code

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ws.Cells.Font.Bold = True
```

May I know how to select and bold the whole sheet by coding with Apache POI library?

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a pretty good example on this [link](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html).

```
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("test");
CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
Font f = wb.createFont();
f.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
cs.setFont(f);
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(1,cs); //set bold for column 1
```

Comment: well yes, it did mentioned how to set the font weight, but how about select the whole sheet?

Comment: As far as I know you have to do it for each column. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Agreed, after few more searches, it seems I can only bold for cell and nothing else (column can only set the default style which applied in new added cells in future)

Answer (score 10):

The default font for a workbook can be retrieved from index 0. So to modify the font bold setting default for the workbook:

```
private void setWorkbookDefaultFontToBold(Workbook workbook){
    Font defaultFont = workbook.getFontAt(0);
    defaultFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
}
```

It's a really obscure piece of information - it's in the POI [Sheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html) Javadoc for setColumnWidth, in the second or so line:

> "...can be displayed in a cell that is formatted with **the standard font (first font in the workbook)**."

I haven't had to use it heavily, so it may have just happened to work for me (the location and non-prevalence of documentation on it makes me slightly leary of recommending depending on it) but it's somewhere you could start looking

Comment: This style applies to all cells which do not set their own font. E.g. italic or other font name. If you create a new font with `workbook.createFont()`, you have to apply all style definitions again. There is nothing like "inheritance".

Answer (score 1):

```
   private HSSFFont createAndSetFontStyle(HSSFWorkbook wb) {
    HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
    font.setFontName(XSSFFont.DEFAULT_FONT_NAME);
    font.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)10);
    return font;
}


    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
    HSSFFont createfont = createAndSetFontStyle(workBook);
    cellStyle.setFont(createfont);

    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Comment: You should be careful mixing `XSSFFont` with `HSSFFont`.